# Absolute convergence implies convergence in absolute value squared

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I am trying to show that for each sequence of real numbers $\{a_k\}_{k = 1}^\infty$, with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k| < \infty$, we also have that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|^2 < \infty$.

In my "proof", so far I have deduced that for each positive integer $n$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|\right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|\right).
\end{align}
I am tempted to say that taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|\right)^2,
\end{align} but I am not completely convinced of this step. The reason is that all we seem to know is that the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2$ are bounded, but  <s>this</s>  this alone is not sufficient to deduce convergence.

Is it possible to extend the inequality regarding the partial sums to deduce the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|^2$?

Comment: $a_k \to 0$, so that $|a_k|^2 \le |a_k|$ for all but finitely many $k$. – This must have been asked and answered before.

Comment: @MartinR Whoops, looks like this has been asked before more than once. I honestly tried to find a similar question, but couldn't. What should I do?

Comment: There should be a button where you can confirm that the question is a duplicate. Or just wait – I assume that it will be closed by other people with sufficient reputation.

Comment: What? Of course $s_n=\sum_1^n|a_j|^2$ bounded implies convergence. The partial sums  are a non-decreasing sequence, bounded above, hence convergent.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks for that, I didn't know of that result. I'm glad you made me aware of it.